# ¿Cómo hacer el conteo del ultimo registro insertado?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla llamada accesosprueba1, esta tabla almacena información de acceso a alguna aplicación, el campo usuario es el numero de identificación del usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otra tabla llamada cecprueba2 almacena la información del usuario, el campo cec, es el numero de  empresa donde esta el usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la siguiente consulta me muestra cuantos usuarios aparecen en la tabla accesosprueba1

```
select count(A.usuario) as Total, B.cec
from accesosprueba1 A
inner join cecprueba2 B
on A.usuario = B.usuario
group by B.cec
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se podra observar el campo cec el cec 101, el campo Total tiene como dato 3, por que hay 3 registros con el mismo cec.
Pero lo que yo quiero es que solamente me cuente el ultimo registro del usuario, es decir en lugar de 3 seria el numero 2, ya que en la tabla accesosprueba1 el id 6 es el ultimo registro de ese usuario y se cuenta con el id 7.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Tu query lo que hace es sacar el número de usuarios que tiene cada empresa para la cual alguno de sus usuarios accedió a alguna aplicación y te muestra 3 porque la empresa 101, tiene 2 usuarios que accedieron a la aplicación el 10 que accedió 2 veces y el 50 que accedió 1 por lo que realmente está "bien".

Si lo que quieres es mostrar el número de veces que cada usuario accedió a alguna aplicación, en vez de agrupar por el campo cec, podrías agrupar por el campo "aplicación" o bien por cec y aplicación lo cual te daría para cada empresa cuantos usuarios accedieron a cada aplicación.

Comment: Lo que quiero realizar es tomar  los últimos registros que accedieron a la aplicación, es decir tomar el usuario 10 con el id 6 y el usuario 50 con el id 7, para que el resultado sea 2. @kasas12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(T1.usuario) as Total, T2.cec 
from
(
 select max(ida) as ultimo, usuario
 from accesosprueba1
 group by usuario
) T1
inner join cecprueba2 T2 on T1.usuario = T2.usuario
group by T2.cec
```

Primero hacemos una consulta interna que nos devolverá por cada usuario su último registro, para esto agrupamos por el **campo usuario** y aplicamos la **función Max** al **campo ida** esta consulta la juntamos mediante una **cláusula inner join** con la **tabla cecprueba2** a través del **campo usuario** que ambas tienen en común y agrupamos entonces por el **campo cec**, posteriormente seleccionaríamos el total de usuarios agrupados por el **campo cec**.

Answer (score 0):

El escenario que planteas.

```
Create table dbo.AccesosPrueba1 
(ida int, usuario int, aplicacion varchar(3))
Create table dbo.cecprueba2
(idcec int, usuario int, cec int)
go
Insert into dbo.AccesosPrueba1
(ida, usuario, aplicacion)
values
(1,10,'CIG'),
(2,20,'SOL'),
(3,30,'KG'),
(4,40,'CIG'),
(5,23,'CIG'),
(6,10,'CIG'),
(7,50,'CID');
Insert into dbo.cecprueba2
(idcec, usuario, cec)
values
(1,10,101),
(2,20,102),
(3,30,103),
(4,40,104),
(5,50,101),
(6,31,101);
GO
```

A priori parece una subconsulta correlativa. Y una de las formas más simples de implementarla es utilizando el operador apply

```
Select count(ca.usuario) as Total, B.cec
from cecprueba2 B
cross apply
(
    select top(1) usuario 
    from dbo.AccesosPrueba1 a
    where a.usuario = b.usuario
    order by ida desc
) ca
group by B.cec
```

[image: Res]

Si de cada usuario, solo quieres el último registro, entendiendo como último, el que tiene la ida de número mayor, entonces, en el conjunto interior llamado `ca` obtienes ese único registro para abastecer a las filas del conjunto exterior.

[Operador apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

Aquí tienes otras formas de hacer lo mismo.

[Subconsultas correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/subquery-correlativa-y-otras-formas-de-conseguirlo/)

Answer (score 0):

Me da la impresión que estás complicando la lógica, por que puedes contar los usuarios únicos de una manera más simple usando el `DISTINCT`:

```
select count(distinct A.usuario) as Total, 
       B.cec
       from accesosprueba1 A
       inner join cecprueba2 B
             on A.usuario = B.usuario
       group by B.cec
```

El `count(distinct A.usuario)` contará los usuarios único que se encuentren en `accesosprueba1` de esta forma el usuario `10` solo se contará como único haciendo que el resultado sea 2 y no 3.